# Prevent IOS/Safari From Opening App From Link

Tags: html, ios, iphone, safari

I have an application that has an IOS app and a web app.

When a user forgets their password, they get an email with this link:

`https://my.domain.com/SetPassword/?code=some_code_here`

The IOS app has this domain also tied into its settings ( deep linking domain permission stuff) and when users click this link in their email **on their IOS device**, it opens the app - **not the web page to reset their password**.

Is there a way to prevent this? Open the webpage in a browser, not the app?

Adding the `target="_blank"` does not work.

here is the source `<a>` in the email:
(formatted for readability)

```html
<a style="color:#c5534d;
font-family:verdana,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold"
href="https://my.domain.com/SetPassword/?code=some_code_here_test_1"
target="_blank" 
data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://my.domain.com/SetPassword/?code=some_code_here_test_1">
     https://my.domain.com/SetPassword
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, I had to add a `apple-app-site-association` file and make this route exclusive to NOT open to the mobile app.

I had to include `"NOT /myroute/*"` to the paths array. The `NOT` prevents this route from opening the app.

The file for me looks something like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "62AGA19JEA.com.domain.subhost",
                "paths": [
                    "*",
                    "NOT /SetPassword/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html